# Split mirth response

Tags: javascript, rest, http, mirth

I'm working on an api using mirth and my sql. I have to handle very large amount of data so I'd like to know if it's possible to split my response if the number of rows out of my query is higher than a number so that my ram doesn't full. The db output isn't a problem, because signals are stored on my file system. So my idea is to open them, I don't know, ten by ten and send them to the client. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you split it into multiple queries? Do you need to recover if it only sends a partial list and pick up where you left off or would you start over from the beginning?

Comment: No i can't. My idea is to "split" the response setting in the response header "Keep-Alive" in the "Connection" Field. Like usually javascript does sending big files, for example. My aim is to send row ten by ten as response